# the largest integer $n$ for which $n+5$ divivides $n^5+5$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

When we divide $n^5+5$ by $n+5$, we get a remainder $-620$, i.e.,
$n^5+5=K(n+5)-620$ , now how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0):

It means that $$\frac{n^5+5}{n+5} = K -\frac{620}{n+5}$$Assuming $K$ is an integer when $n$ is, how large can $n+5$ be if we want this right-hand side to be an integer?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\,{\rm mod}\ n\!+\!5\!:\  \color{#c00}{n\equiv -5}\,\Rightarrow\, P(\color{#c00}n)\equiv P(\color{#c00}{-5})\ $ so $\,n\!+\!5\mid P(n)\iff n\!+\!5\mid P(-5),\ $ by the [Polynomial Congruence Rule,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) for $\,P(x)\,$ any polynomial with integer coefficients.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2216759/242) for elaboration.